# Can't seem to get EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster running

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to write some unit and integration tests for my application that uses a Kafka producer and consumer. I want to run a EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster using the class available to spin up 1 ZK and 1 Kafka broker. I'm unable to do so - it is failing to spin up the cluster and I'm unable to create a Kafka Producer.

Has anyone faced this issue and if so, what was your take on writing unit/integration tests?

Comment: You probably found the answer by now, but remember to always include details of exactly how you are trying to start `EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster` and the error you are getting, otherwise even if someone had the same problem they wouldn't recognize it.